# Should the imam make a special intention for leading a fard prayer?

Tags: salat, imam-al-jamaah

Please let me know the neeyat for imam.

During fard salat in company, one of us takes place of imam and leads the prayer. How should that person make neeyat for the prayer?  Is it any different than the regular neeyat one would make for praying alone?

Answer (score 2):

Aleikum Assalam

In general There's no need to say any word as Niyat (intention). When you plan to do something that's is enough for Niyat (no need to say something).

Please consider that [Imam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imam) (leader of prayer) should have qualification. Check those please.

Answer (score 2):

Walykum Salam,

As per the hadith of prophet SAW:

> Book of Revelation
> Bukhari :: Book 1 :: Volume 1 :: Hadith 1
> Narrated ‘Umar bin Al-Khattab:
>
> I heard Allah’s Apostle saying, “The reward of deeds depends upon the intentions and every person will get the reward according to what he has intended. So whoever emigrated for worldly benefits or for a woman to marry, his emigration was for what he emigrated for.”
>
> Also reported in Sahih Muslim

So in the light of this hadith your intention i.e. your act of thinking about offering prayer in heart, is actually your niyat, and you are not required to say that niyat words.

And Allah knows the best.

Source:

[Islam QA](http://islamqa.info/en/37841)

Answer (score 1):

assalamualaikum, you don't have to say it in words it can be in the heart. But if you say it you would say your making the intention of such fard salah facing allah and for his sake and you are the imam if you are the imam and it does not have to be said in Arabic it can be said in English or the best language you know or it can be from the heart. I hope allah guides us all and gives you the tawfiq and us the twfiq too to understand his deen fully. And he grants us jannatul firdaus for trying to learn his words or trying to talk to allah because salah is like you talking to allah and it's like your time with allah. So may allah accept our intentions of any good deeds.

There is probably a lot of mistakes or my English might be a bit poor because I'm 15 and don't really concentrate in school. Some people that are older they won't listen to advice of youngers I don't really know why. Maybe because they are young they think the youngers have less knowledge.  jazakumullah